# how to get the tasks taking more size on RAM in linux

Tags: linux, ram

With the command `free -g`, I am able to get the total occupied size and free size of RAM in Linux. But want to understand which tasks or process taking more size, so that I can free up the RAM size.

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:           125        121          4          0          6         94
-/+ buffers/cache:         20        105
Swap:           31          0         31
```

Comment: See the `top` command. You can sort on all sorts of memory usage fields.

Comment: it gives me the percentage of memory occupied for each process.

Comment: Isn't that what you want?

Comment: I am looking for the process id's which took 121 GB of RAM size

Comment: If any process which is running in background which occupying RAM size, I want to kill those process's

Comment: In that case you probably want to run a `ps -e` listing. `ps` can output different information about each process, I believe memory usage is one. Check you manpage to make sure. `ps` piped to an awk/perl/python/etc script should do the trick for you.

Answer (score 3):

Go for top command

then press shift+f

press a for pid information

ALso check

ps -eo pmem,vsz,pid

man ps

checkout pmem,vsz,pid.......

hope it helps..
thanks for the question !

Comment: When I am pressing a, it gives the process id's but the memory usage is 0.0%, not sure how my RAM size occupied full.

Answer (score 1):

You can use below command to find running processes sorted by memory use:

`ps -eo pmem,pcpu,rss,vsize,args | sort -k 1 -r | less`